# Pass in one argument to constructor of dependency injection class, that will also have a dependency injected argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

I am converting .net framework to .net 5.0 and using the built in dependency injection in .net 5.0 instead of Ninject library I used in .net framework.

I have the following constructor that takes in a messageHandler (through dependency injection) as well as a web service root address:

(old) 1.

```
public ApiConnection(HttpMessageHandler messageHandler, string webServiceRootAddress)
```

Here is the setup for the dependency injection through ninject in .net framework:

(old) 2.

```
kernel.Bind<IApiConnection>().To<ApiConnection>().InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument(
        "webServiceRootAddress",
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webServiceRootAddress"]);
```

(old) 3.

```
kernel.Bind<HttpMessageHandler>().To<HttpClientHandler>();
```

I want to set up the above in the built in dependency injection in .net 5 within the Startup file.

I currently have the following:

(new doesn't work) 4.

```
services.AddSingleton<IApiConnection, ApiConnection>(s =>
    new ApiConnection(Configuration.GetSection("Address")
        .GetSection("webServiceRootAddress").Value));
```

(new) 5.

```
services.AddScoped<HttpMessageHandler, HttpClientHandler>();
```

But the above is expecting 2 arguments to be passed into the constructor. How do I define only one constructor argument to be passed in here, because the HttpMessageHandler argument will be passed in through dependency injection (line 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few options, here's a couple of them.

1. Use the `s` parameter to get the service:

   ```
   services.AddSingleton<IApiConnection, ApiConnection>(s => 
   {
       var rootAddress = Configuration.GetSection("Address")
           .GetSection("webServiceRootAddress")
           .Value;
       var messageHandler = s.GetRequiredService<HttpMessageHandler>();
       return new ApiConnection(messageHandler, rootAddress );
   });
   ```
2. Pass in a service/class that gets the root address:

   ```
   public class MyConfig
   {
       public string WebServiceRootAddress { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Add the service to your DI container:

   ```
   services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Address")
       .GetSection("webServiceRootAddress"));
   ```

   Now modify your `ApiConnection` service to take the class instead of the string:

   ```
   public ApiConnection(HttpMessageHandler messageHandler, MyConfig myConfig)
   {
       var webServiceRootAddress = myConfig.WebServiceRootAddress;
   }
   ```